# Full fat or skinny DTO objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dto

Do I want to return Full-Fat Dtos; i.e. with basic parent entity info, it's Id and name, and collections of child entities converted to collections of child dtos; or strip everything back and only return ids for parent entities?

The skinny choice will appear result in lots of calls back to the web-api to fill in the missing details, but the full-fat dto will be a fairly heavy object if an entity has many child, grand-child, etc relationships.

Is there a semi-skimmed option to halt dto serialization at a certain level?

To add some additional context: we are wrapping a 3rd party api for internal use. The 3rd party is using the "skinny" approach to return ~18,000 entities, about 18mb.

For this to be anything more than a collection of ids we need add at least some context. Id and Name entities are simple enough to include but where the related fields may have child relationships which due to underlying database design lead to interesting circular relationships things get interesting...

Comment: This isn't really answerable in its current form. There is no silver bullet. The answer is "it depends". Only you know what exactly you need and which options are viable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always tended toward the "full-fat" DTO-approach, as you've dubbed it. Performance is a feature, and there's no better way to reduce performance than to add a bunch of unnecessary network latency.

I would say unless you're dealing with a severely resource strapped machine, than go full-fat, at the benefit of reducing the number of round trips to and from the server.

You haven't given much information, but I suppose that you're backed by DB tables here? If so, I prefer to expose the "entities" as pure representations of individual DB records (obviously omitting sensitive fields). And creating a [RESTful](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/urls.html#entry-point) API to expose and navigate it.

> EDIT: To elaborate with some code on what I mean by "full-fat" (note:
>   certain superfluous details are omitted to reduce the verbosity).

**Example SQL setup:**

```
create table dbo.User (
    Id int identity primary key,
    Name nvarchar(50)
);

create table dbo.Post (
    Id int identity primary key,
    UserId int not null foreign key references dbo.User(Id),
    Title nvarchar(50),
    Body nvarchar(max)
);
```

**Example CLR Objects:**

```
public sealed class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Post 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }   
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Given the above setup, an example on how to expose the object(s) RESTfully would be as follows:

```
/api/users            /*users collection*/
/api/users/1          /*user resource*/
/api/users/1/posts    /*user resource with posts sub-collection*/

/api/posts            /*posts collection*/
/api/posts/1?user=1|0 /*post resource with/without User*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer is "Do you need "Full-Fat" Dto?"

Return only data you need. 
For example Customer-Orders structure

- For method which going to use only `customer.Id` and `customer.Name` you can return only `{ Id: 1, Name: "One" }`
- For method which need more customer's info you will return more info
  `{ Id: 1, Name: "One", Street: "Street 12", City: "City" }`
- For method which need more complex data you will create api which
  return more complex data

Do not try to be generic from the beginning, develop concrete API methods your applications need, then you can see whole picture and refactor methods to be more generic, play with different tradeoffs

Answer (score 0):

The choice entirely depends on the context you have to apply your solution in.

I usually mix the two. If I have a 'master-detail' type of view, for example a webshop, and I have to display products in a list where the user only sees the name and the price of product, then I choose a 'skinny' version. Then, the user can click on the product to see the details page, I send the 'full-fat' version.

But if there is a category associated with each product, I would probably only send the categoryid and maybe the name of the category in the 'detail' product dto. Then, when the user clicks on a category to see category details and maybe other products, I'd send the rest.